# Eclipse - Hibernate : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to learn Hibernate by writing a simple java program. I'm using MySQL as the database, and I get the above error when running the program. I saw a number of solutions for this on the internet and tried everything possible, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping resource="com/test/hibernate/student.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Console output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at com.test.hibernate.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
    ... 5 more
```

Classpath & lib folder:
[image: Classpath & lib folder]

[image: lib folder]

Comment: Add the MySql Connector/J driver on your CLASSPATH to resolve the issue.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer , looks like its already included as its there in image provided by OP

Comment: try using jdk instead of jre

Comment: Are you running the program from Eclipse or from the command line?

Comment: @gundev Just tried, not working.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm running it from Eclipse itself..

Comment: @Ruwangi , can you check if its being included in the runtime classpath?

Comment: @AmitK It's already there..

Comment: @Ruwangi , i know its there in the image but thats your compile time classpath and i asked for runtime classpath

Comment: @AmitK How do I do that? I added the driver to the classpath and the project buildpath.. Do I have to add it anywhere else?

Comment: how you are running it ? are you using embeded server in eclipse or creating a war file and manually deploying it.

Comment: @AmitK I am not doing either. This is just a simple Java program, not a web app or anything, so do I need a server? Please note that I am a complete beginner in this. I'm following this particular tutorial: http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/hibernate/hibernate_example_in_eclipse.php -and it doesn't say anything like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142489/discussion-between-amitk-and-ruwangi).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't add the mysql-connector library correctly, because in the snapshot from the Run configuration you posted, that library appears within a project called "hibernate test" which contains a file named "mysql-connector-etc.jar", but that is not the way to set a JAR within a classpath.

Do it this way: It's better that you add the "mysql-connector-etc.jar" right within your project's Java Build Path: Pop up the project's contextual menu, and the `Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries > Add external jars`. Then select the mysql-connector JAR and enter. From then on, Eclipse will include this JAR into any execution of your project you should do (so you won't have to care about it anymore).